# Understanding execution flow in asynchronous functions

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

consider the following code. It was grabbed from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequestoptions-callback).

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(URL, options, res => {
        let rawData = '';

        res.on('data', chunk => {
            rawData += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            resolve(rawData);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', err => {
        reject(new Error(err));
    });

    req.end();
});
```

I think I've got a pretty clear understanding of how this works.

When I call the function that contains this code, a promise will be returned.

Inside this function when `https.request` is executed, I am passing in a callback function. In side the `https.request` code, it will callback this function to process certain events. In this case, it looks like to receive data, or to catch the end of the connection. If the end of the connection is detected, the parent promise will be fulfilled and the data will be returned to the calling application.

However, later in this function, I am looking at the returned `req` object and detecting an `error` event to reject the parent promise. And finally, the `end` method of `https.request` is called to close the connection.

My question is this, when does the code after the `https.request` execute? That is, the `req.on('error'...)` and the `req.end()`.

My understanding suggests a couple of different things...

1. The `https.request` returns a promise and then the `req.on('error'...)` and `req.end()` code is executed. But, if that were true, then it appears it would potentially end the request before it had time to complete the request or process any data.

or

2. The `https.request` blocks execution and a promise is returned to the caller. The `req.on('error'...)` and `req.end()` does not execute until the `https.request` resolves. This would be akin to using `await` on the `https.request`? But, if that were the case, when would I write a stream to the `req` object to upload a file on a POST request? I'm assuming right after the `req.on('error'...)` and before the `req.end()`? However, if I did that, how would I get a response from the server after the stream completes?

Basically, I would like to understand the program execution flow in the code, along with any explanation why based on the async/promise functionality. I specifically don't understand if https.request returns a promise in async mode or blocks code execution in await mode based on the fact a callback function was provided.

Answer (score 0):

> I am passing in a callback function. In side the `https.request` code, it will callback this function to process certain events.

No. The callback you're passing is called *asychronously* (not sure if that counts as "within" in your book) when a response is received. That response is a stream on which then the `data` and `end` event listeners are installed (which again will be invoked asynchronously).

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpgetoptions-callback) say "*The `callback` is invoked with a single argument that is an instance of [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage).*" or [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequesturl-options-callback) "*The optional callback parameter will be added as a one-time listener for the [`'response'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-response).*"

<sup>(Admittedly I needed to link the `http` docs instead of the `https` ones, since those only document the difference from http but work the same otherwise)</sup>

> The `https.request` returns a promise

No it doesn't. It returns without blocking, no promises involved.

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequestoptions-callback) say: "*`https.request()` returns an instance of the [`http.ClientRequest` class](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest). The `ClientRequest` instance is a writable stream. If one needs to upload a file with a POST request, then write to the `ClientRequest` object.*"

So execution returns immediately from the `https.request()` call, without waiting for anything. On this request object, an `error` handler is installed, then the request is finished (and flushed) by calling `.end()` since we don't want to send a body.

Then the `new Promise` executor callback concludes, the new promise is returned somewhere, and usually the code that made the call will `await` it or call `.then()` to install fulfillment/rejection handlers on the promise.

Only after all this happened, at some later point in time, the `response` or `error` events will occur.

Answer (score 0):

`end` doesn't close the connection. It [actually](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestenddata-encoding-callback) starts sending it. The delegate passed to the `Promise` constructor is executed immediately (before the promise is returned to your code).

The delegate passed to `request` is executed when (and if) the response arrives.

Comment: "*It actually starts sending it*" - not really, it **finishes** sending the request (as the very docs you linked state). Admittedly, it does flush the request, but the headers would already have been sent by the `https.request` call itself.